# Create jar file online convert show me error

Tags: java, executable-jar

i have following code of java, how to create jar file because when i create jar file its show me error please help me , jarfile name and folder same as i enter in zip please convert only zip to jar. i was convert zip to jar but my jar file does not run. thats why i am here

[Zip File Link convert to jar file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5RS5NvX8ecCakdvLXhGY3ZIbW8)

Comment: create a zip file, adding the contents of the cli directory and rename the file from .zip to .jar

Comment: i am dotnet developer i try and convert zip to jar but my jarfile does not run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using netbeans IDE then right click on the project name go to properties->build->packaging.

check build jar after compiling option and ok. then click on clean and build project.

You will find your jar file in the dist folder.

EDIT: if you are using Eclipse IDE check this post. [how to create jar file using eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21110972/3968623)

Comment: You should probably mention what IDE these instructions are for.

Comment: i am dotnet developer i don't have any IDE of java ;(

Comment: You can download it !