# How to generate source code jar file of project java files?

Tags: java

I want to see my project code through attached source in eclipse , but my jar file does not contain java source code , so how to create jar file with source code.

Comment: Please leave some more info, how you create your jar? Are you using eclipse for that? Or a build tool like maven, ant or gradle? The answer could depend on that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to create jar file using eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981958/how-to-create-jar-file-using-eclipse)

Comment: provide some more information about your question? It is not clear.

Comment: @KhairulBasarRofi I am not sure if this duplicate is correct. It looks like OP is not asking how to create JAR with `.class` files (binaries), but one with `.java` files (source), like when we import external libraries, we have choice of jar with only classes and one with sourcecode if we want to inspect it with our IDEs. Probably like in https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi

Comment: @Pshemo Question in unclear. May be you are right and i misunderstood the question.

Comment: @KhairulBasarRofi True, I am not saying it is not. All I am saying is that duplicate may not be what OP wants so people shouldn't blindly vote/flag for it as such.

Comment: Yeah ! right ! :( @Pshemo

Comment: @RajuKapadne since you seem new on Stack Overflow you may not be aware that there is [edit] option below your question. Use it to clarify it. Maybe add some simple example of your project structure and what JARs should contain.