# Creating Windows EXE from Java(FX) through Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I can't create Windows software through Eclipse. Using "Run" does run the app as it should, but I would like to start it without Eclipse, preferably as an independent Windows app, using a mere double-click.
Although [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file) suggests several approaches, they all require additional knowledge that I do not posses.

I have tried using Launch4J but it also requires additional knowledge. I am astounded that it is so difficult to create a simple Windows-Java-app.

EDIT
I am using this pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>foo</groupId>
<artifactId>bar</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<name>baz</name>
<description></description>

<dependencies>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.8.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>application.Main</mainClass>
                <updateExistingJar>true</updateExistingJar>
                <skipCopyingDependencies>true</skipCopyingDependencies>
                <useLibFolderContentForManifestClasspath>true</useLibFolderContentForManifestClasspath>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

But Eclipse gives this error message:

```
Failed to execute goal com.zenjava:javafx-maven-plugin:8.8.3:build-jar
```

the goal being

```
clean compile package -e
```

Maven is installed, trying to run it with minimal appendancies.

Comment: My project can bundle your app into an MSI file and even bundle in the JRE so end user does not need Java installed.  It is a bit complex though.  https://github.com/pquiring/javaforce

Comment: @stdunbar The post you are pointing to requires advanced knowledge of Java programming, including additional software. Wow, is it still so hard to develop a simple Java app which does the same as clicking the run-button in Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Launch4j I know it can make an exe Wrapper over the Java, and it is cross platform.

Check here:
http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/

Comment: It requires additional knowledge. Before you tell me to simply learn it, try developing a minimal approach.

Comment: What additional knowledge are you talking about ?
You select output .exe file, and input .jar file. Maybe they changed something lately, but I remember you need 1-2 clicks.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you can't create "Windows-Java-App". Java applications run on JVM (Java Virtual Machine) which means you wont be getting an exe file. What you need is a JAR file. For info on how to create a JAR file in Eclipse, see here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21110972/4440179

For JavaFX follow this guide: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Efxclipse/Tutorials/Tutorial1

Comment: It is possible to create "Windows-Java-Apps".  You can even bundle the JRE into the MSI that is distributed so the user need not have Java installed.  Java is just a DLL when you think about it.

Comment: I did export the app as a "Runnable Jar file" with different selections ("Extract required [...]", "Package required [...]", "Copy required [...]". Double clicking the resulting JAR file did not start the app.

Comment: Yea, this answer doesn't really help Op at all. As Peter says, you *can* create "Windows-Java-Apps", but also this answer just doesn't tell Op anything about making the Jar able to run as a JavaFX application.

Comment: @Alleavingmarks does your app have a GUI?

Comment: @JimS Op says, it's JavaFX. There's no point in JavaFX without a GUI my dude..

Comment: @JimS Yes, that is why JavaFX is used.

Comment: @Alleavingmarks sorry didn't notice the JavaFX in the title. Anyways, without any more info about the app, code etc. I can't tell what's wrong. But this is the way to create an executable.

Comment: @JimS Since this does not answer Ops question I recommend deleting this.

Comment: @xtratic He asked quoting "I would like to start it without Eclipse, preferably as an independent Windows app, using a mere double-click.". He asks for a JAR file. I redirected him to an answer with steps on how to create one in Eclipse. How does this not help OP?

Comment: Your answer does not work for Ops request for a double-clickable JavaFX Jar.

Comment: @JimS "He asks for a JAR file." All that I am asking for is a minimal approach to run a (Java-)app on Windows with minimal effort.

Comment: @Alleavingmarks `java -jar jar_name.jar` run this through the command line to check if your app is throwing an exception.

Comment: @JimS Building a JavaFX Jar is not the same as building a normal Jar.

Comment: @Alleavingmarks I edited my answer for JavaFX apps.

Comment: @JimS This command-line approach does start it as inteded. Thank you. The main problem is still that I do not have a mere double-click approach.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend making a `Maven` project to help you build an executable JavaFX Jar.

Firstly you'll need to make sure that Eclipse has the Maven plugin `Help -> About Eclipse IDE` and make sure that `Eclipse.org - m2e` is installed.

Then make a Maven project `New -> Other.. -> Maven Project`, fill in the basic stuff to create the project then put your source files under `src/main/java` of this new project.

There should be a `pom.xml` file in the root of this new project; This file helps manage your project dependencies and build process.
To make easily build an executeable add the below plugins to your `pom.xml` file to modify the build process.

Then you can just right click your `pom.xml` then `Run As -> Maven Build ...` then put `clean compile package -e` as your goals, refresh your `MyProject/target` directory and find your Jar under `MyProject/target/javafx/app/jarname.jar`

Also, if you want, you can look into using the launch4j maven plugin to have maven build the native executable for you, else your Jar will require the user have Java installed but it will still be a double-clickable JavaFX Jar.

---

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>foo</groupId>
<artifactId>bar</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<name>baz</name>
<description></description>

<dependencies>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.8.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>path.to.my.Main</mainClass>
                <updateExistingJar>true</updateExistingJar>
                <skipCopyingDependencies>true</skipCopyingDependencies>
                <useLibFolderContentForManifestClasspath>true</useLibFolderContentForManifestClasspath>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: Is Maven a requirement for running any Java-app on Windows? I doubt it.

Comment: No, maven is just a build tool. It makes it easier for you to build your projects. I also had trouble making an executable JavaFX application until I used maven.

Comment: I tried Maven, but I get the error message "No goals have been specified for this build". Professionals might know right away which goals need to be specified, but I simply want to run my app ...

Comment: Sorry, right click `Run As -> Maven Build ...` then put `clean compile package -e` as your goals

Comment: I get the "The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory" message.

Comment: Didn't you click on the `pom.xml` file? Is your project not a Maven Java project? It should have a little `m` to the left of the `J` over your project folder. Please paste the contents of your `pom` into your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186567/discussion-between-xtratic-and-al-leaving-marks).

Comment: I put the pom.xml file in the root, but the following error appears when I try to run it: "Malformed POM"

Comment: Sorry, I had only pasted the `<build>` section of the `pom` the full `pom` should look more like what I have edited into my answer now. You're almost there, once you understand Maven a little more it will make life much easier for you. Also you will need to specify the path to your main JavaFX class in place of `path.to.my.Main`

Comment: I get an error message consisting of "BUILD FAILURE" and "Failed to execute goal com.zenjava:javafx-maven-plugin:8.8.3:build-jar".

Comment: please add the contents of your `pom.xml` to your question. Also, let's continue in chat, please click the link above.